# Get sum of key values in deep array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes like

```
array = [
  { john: {win: 10, lose: 20}, mike: {win: 5, lose: 5} },
  { john: {win: 10, lose: 20}, mike: {win: 5, lose: 5} },
  { john: {win: 10, lose: 20}, mike: {win: 5, lose: 5} }
]
```

I want to sum, all of the wins and all of the lose for john and same for mike. So the result will be like

```
result = { john: {win: 30, lose: 60}, mike: {win: 15, lose: 15}}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you tried to solve by your own? Brute force or any dynamic solution code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `ruby-on-rails` tag, you can use Ruby method [`#inject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) with Rails method [`#deep_merge`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge):

```rb
array.inject do |hash1, hash2|
  hash1.deep_merge(hash2) do |key, hash1_val, hash2_val|
    hash1_val + hash2_val
  end
end

=> {:john=>{:win=>30, :lose=>60}, :mike=>{:win=>15, :lose=>15}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
result = {}
array.each do |element|
  element.each do |user, score|
    result[user] ||= { win: 0, lose: 0 }
    result[user][:win] += score[:win]
    result[user][:lose] += score[:lose]
  end
end
```

Result:

```
p result
 => {:john=>{:win=>30, :lose=>60}, :mike=>{:win=>15, :lose=>15}}
```